# Error bars on log scale using errorbarxy in matlab

Tags: matlab

In matlab I am using [errorbarxy](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19002-errorbarxy) to plot x and y error bars. However, with a log scale on both x and y axes, the error bars do not look right - i.e. the error bar 'heads' are different sizes. How can I fix this?

```
X = 10 * rand(7,1);
Y = 10 * rand(7,1);
ux = rand(7,1);
uy = rand(7,1);
lx = rand(7,1);
ly = rand(7,1);
errorbarxy(X,Y,ux,uy,lx,ly,'Color','k','LineStyle','none','Marker','o','MarkerFaceColor','w','MarkerSize',11);
set(gca,'YScale','log');
set(gca,'XScale','log');
print -r600 -dtiff myplot.tif
```

[image]

Comment: "...the error bars do not look right." – can you be more specific or, ideally, provide an image and/or runnable code that replicates the issue?

Comment: @horchler sorry - edited now

Comment: In `errorbarxy.m`, try changing `xw` and `yw` so that they are equal, i.e., from this: `xw = (max(x)-min(x))/100; yw = (max(y)-min(y))/100;` to this maybe `xw=max(max(x)-min(x),max(y)-min(y))/100; yw=xw;`.

Comment: You should be able to use normal options such as `LineColor`, `Color`, etc. for the error bars too.

Comment: Is it possible that you linked the wrong version of errorbarxy? The one you linked to does indeed have the line @David mentioned. Also it has a different argument order than your code and results suggest.

Comment: @David  thanks - sorry my .m file must have been an old version. OK, the color sepcs work with this one. I will try the modification for log axes. Thanks!

Comment: @David thanks for your help - unfortunately this doesn't seem to have worked (the errorbar 'heads' are different sizes)

Comment: @knowledgemonger please see edits - thanks

Comment: Yes, I think I see why the heads would be a different size, due to the log scale. I see no obvious workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use [ploterr](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22216-ploterr) instead.

from the documentation:
The following features are supported:

- linear/**logarithmic** scaling
- x and/or y error bars
- relative/absolute errors
- width of bar handles adjustable